# Как написать в одной ячейке слова слева справа и по центру на HTML

Tags: html

Нужно расположить три слова в одной ячейке таблицы HTML

Comment: отлично, и как у вас получилось?

Answer (score 2):

Вариант 1

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
}

td {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.td_l {
  float: left;
}

.td_r {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="td_l"><span class="td_l">Вот</span>Вам<span class="td_r">3 слова</span></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Вариант 2

```js
$(function() {
  $('.table_js').each(function() {
    var val = this.innerHTML;
    val = val.replace(/(\S*)/, '<span class=td_js_l>$1</span>');
    this.innerHTML = val;
  });
  $('.table_js').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.html($this.html().replace(/(\S+)\s*$/, '<span class="td_js_r">$1</span>'));
  });
});
```

```css
table {
  width: 400px;
}

td {
  width: 400px;
  text-align: center;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: 5px;
}

.td_js_l {
  float: left;
}

.td_js_r {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td class="table_js">Вот Вам 3_слова</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 2):

Равномерно:

```css
td {
width: 300px;
display: flex;
border: 1px solid red;
justify-content:space-around
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<span>Слово1</span>
<span>Слово2</span>
<span>Слово3</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Или по краям и центру:

```css
td {
width: 300px;
display: flex;
border: 1px solid red;
justify-content:space-between
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<span>Слово1</span>
<span>Слово2</span>
<span>Слово3</span>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```